# Amazon SDK overrides autoloader

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

It seems as the AWS SDK for PHP overrides the __autoload() function. Undeclared classes can't be found after including the AWS SDK.

```
require_once( "AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar" );
new ClassA();
```

ClassA() exists in my __autoload() function but the code above gives the error below.

> Fatal error: Class 'ClassA' not found in /path/classa.php on line 2

Removing require_once( "AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar" ); does not give me this error. This is the SDK I use installed through PEAR: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php
Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
require_once( "AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar" );
```

reset the autoloader back to `spl_autoload`, and add the AWS autoloader using `spl_autoload_register`

```
require_once( "AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar" );
__autoload('spl_autoload');
spl_autoload_register(/* whatever you find AWS registers */);
```

Comment: It seems as I made a mistake. It was the old AWS SDK for PHP that used spl_autoload_register(). The new SDK I have no idea how it works: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php

Comment: Both use spl_autoload_register, since that is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You should never, ever use `__autoload()`. You should always, always use `spl_autoload_register()` because it's stackable.